# Show each list item in a different page of the pdf

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query and Im using the package "https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf" to show the results in pdf format:

```
public function getRegistrationInfo($regID){
    $registration = Registration::with('conference',Conference.registrationTypes','Conference.registrationTypes.participants')
            ->where('id',$regID)->first();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.registration', compact('registration'));

    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

And in the view "pdf.registration" I have this to show the query results:

```
@foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType)

        <li>
            <span>show the registration ID here : {{$registration->id}}</span> <br>
            <span>Conference name {{$registration->conference->name}}</span><br>
            <span>Registration type: {{$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name']}}</span><br>
            <span> Participant: {{$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]
            ->participants[0]->name .' '.$registration->
            conference->registrationTypes[$key]->participants[0]->surname}}</span><br>
            <span>Price: {{$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['price']}}</span><br>
        </li>

    @endforeach
```

And its working when the user clicks on the button to download the pdf the pdf is downloaded. For now it returns 2 results, 2 list items, and both list items appears on the first page of the pdf. But I want to have each list item in one page of the pdf. Do you know how what is necessary to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do page break by using below html and css in your page -

put the below html wherever you want to do page break.

```
<div class="breakNow"></div>
```

In your css code:

```
div.breakNow { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:always; }
```

After this your pdf should also have content in the next page.

Comment: Thanks, but still appears on the same page with with:  "@foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType)<div class="breakNow"></div><li>.....</li>@endforeach".

Comment: Adding the css styles on the same page like "     div.breakNow { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:always; }...</style> it works, thanks!